# Facebook Like Button doesn't increment

Tags: facebook-like, increment

I've added some like buttons on my personal web page: [edoardo.torreggiani.net](http://edoardo.torreggiani.net) but only one button works fine.

**THIS WORKS** (homepage):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fedoardo.torreggiani.net&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;locale=en_US" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 21px; " allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK** (single post in homepage):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fedoardo.torreggiani.net%2Fhome%3Fpost%3D5&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;locale=en_US" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 21px; " allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When I click on the like button that doesn't work I obtain that **response** :

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"jsmods":{"require":[["Plugin","disconnect",[],["http:\/\/edoardo.torreggiani.net\/home?post=5"]]]}}
```

The only difference between the working one and the wrong one is the **HREF param** in *iframe src*: the wrong one has one parameter in query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, there is no real page for every blogpost. Your post link is this one:

```
http://edoardo.torreggiani.net/home?post=5
```

Put that in the debugger and you will see errors:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fedoardo.torreggiani.net%2Fhome%3Fpost%3D5
```

> Object at URL 'http://edoardo.torreggiani.net' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '10150406244527145' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

Comment: And how can I solve my problem in easy way? My goal is to make likable all my posts.

Comment: well, you have to make sure that "http://edoardo.torreggiani.net/home?post=5" links to the post, because right now it just doesn´t. you might want to get rid of that weird loader to fix this...

Comment: I've fixed the problems related to facebook debugger and now I can see the counter increment but it works only for one post at time! To make the others likable I have to make a page refresh (by F5)..and after that all like buttons work fine....any suggestions for that point?